# How can you get a date range based on when another value stops being the same consecutively?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here's a sample of my data:

```
VendingID  Date        SnackType   User     TotalBought
 9          2014-11-30  chocolate   ben      10
 9          2015-11-30  chocolate   frank    12
 9          2016-11-30  chocolate   ben      9
 9          2014-11-30  crisps      ben      10
 9          2015-11-30  crisps      frank    12
 9          2016-11-30  crisps      ben      9
 10         2014-11-30  chocolate   ben      10
 10         2015-11-30  chocolate   frank    12
 10         2016-11-30  chocolate   ben      9
 10         2017-11-30  chocolate   frank    7
 10         2018-11-30  chocolate   frank    7
 10         2019-11-30  chocolate   frank    6
 10         2014-11-30  crisps      frank    9
 10         2015-11-30  crisps      frank    7
 10         2016-11-30  crisps      ben      9
 10         2017-11-30  crisps      frank    7
 10         2018-11-30  crisps      ben      3
 10         2019-11-30  crisps      ben      2
```

Is it possible to sum the number of total bought snacks by type for a given VendingID, for the user that is the one at the most recent date, going back only consecutive years until the user changes?

So the expected result for VendingID 10 would be: for chocolate the user would be 'frank', which would sum 2019, 2018, and 2017 only as there is then a change in the user, which would return the value of 6 + 7 + 7 = 20. In the same query I would also like to return the same for crisps, so the user would be 'ben' summing only 2019 and 2018, which would be 2 + 3 = 5. So the returned result would be:

`SnackType  SumTotalBought
 chocolate  20
 crisps     5`

So I think I can get the SnackType and USer by VendingID for the current (most recent) date, but don't know how to get the range that relates to the consecutive years so I can sum the TotalBought:

```
SELECT SnackType, User
FROM vendingOptions vo
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Date) as maxDate
      FROM vendingOptions vo2
      WHERE VendingID = '10') as md
ON md.maxDate = vo.Date
WHERE VendingID = '10'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I'm not sure if "consecutive years" is really important, or just the final run all for the same user.  Let me assume it is the latter:

```
select vendingid, snacktype, sum(totalbought)
from (select vo.*,
             max(case when user <> last_user then date end) over (partition by vendingid) as last_nonuserdate
      from (select vo.*,
                   first_value(vo.user) over (partition by vendingid order by date desc) as last_user
            from vendingoptions vo
           ) vo
     ) vo
where date > last_nonuserdate or last_nonuserdate is null
group by vendingid, snacktype
order by vendingid, snacktype;
```

The innermost subquery finds the last user for each vendor.  The middle subquery then finds the latest date for *other* users.  The outer query filters and aggregates.

Comment: how would that work the formatting is a bit off but at first seight i believe WHERE last_nonuserdate uses the last_nonuserdate alias on the same select level..

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the 'last_nonuserdate' in the where clause. It says invalid column name. Replacing the alias with the actual max code gives the error 'Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses'

Comment: @sr28 . . . As I explained in the logic, the filtering should be in the outermost query.  I fixed the query to follow that explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the update and the time you've put into this. However, I'm now getting an error of `ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame cannot contain expressions of LOB type.` From what I understand this means one of my objects is considered a Large Object, so just need to figure that out

Comment: Looks like the snackType for some reason has been setup as a varchar(max), which is most likely the issue. Let me fix and see if this works.